# Why am I getting a HTTP 403 error with Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Looking to grab data from tables on a specific esport site and I appear to be struggling.

Was told that pandas library could help me achieve this with just a few lines.

```
import pandas as pd


tables = pd.read_html ('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/5752/Cloud9')

print(tables[0])
```

I try to edit it to make mine work yet I have no success.

```
import pandas as pd

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/5752/Cloud9',     headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

tables = pd.read_html ('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/5752/Cloud9)

print(tables[0])
```

I was lead to believe this may be the solution I was looking for, or something similar to it, but when I try to resolve the issue in this fashion, I have no success.

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Documents\Python\tables clloud9.py", line 6, in <module>
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"
```

All I want at the moment is for the table on the link to be pulled.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/5752/Cloud9',     headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

tables = pd.read_html ('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/matches/5752/Cloud9') #here was the err

print(tables[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because server security feature which blocks known spider/bot user agents Urlib can be easily spotted and blocked by anti-scraping tools, especially with the header you are using. Try passing through one of the user agents found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) into the header and see if one of those ones works.

However in your specific case, the [robots.txt file](https://www.hltv.org/robots.txt) disallows crawlers on the stats page, so they are probably blocking all known crawlers including the Urllib.

Follow the example [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251) to try **scraping** using Selenium. Selenium looks more like a user than a **scraper** so it is often (at least for me) used as a work around when you get a HTTP Error 403: Forbidden".